# How can I decode response data if data is nested in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, decodable

I've got a problem with decoding response data. Here is my request function

```
  @IBAction func onGetCities(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://somelink.com/city-list") else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in


        print(JSON(data))
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do{
            let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: data)
            print(cities)
        }catch{

        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And City struct

```
struct City: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let city: String
}
```

Here is the response data, I want to decode "items"

```
{
"offset": 0,
"limit": 10,
"items": [
  {id: 0, name: "City name"},
  {id: 1, name: "City name1"},
  .....
]

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to have nested structures that mirror your nested JSON:

```
struct City: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let city: String
}

struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let items: [City]
    let offset: Int
    let limit: Int
}
```

And then:

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    print(result)

    let cities = result.items
    print(cities)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Note, in your original example, you included a JSON key, `updated_at` which was the date represented in number of seconds since 1970 (standard UNIX representation). So, to decode that:

```
struct City: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let city: String
}

struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let items: [City]
    let offset: Int
    let limit: Int
    let code: Int
    let updatedAt: Date
}
```

And then:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    print(result)

    let cities = result.items
    print(cities)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Note, when you see a somewhat abstract key name, such as `items`, that means that this might be a response structure used for various endpoints. In that case, we might to make this a [generic](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics):

```
struct ItemsResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let items: [T]
    let offset: Int
    let limit: Int
    let code: Int
    let updatedAt: Date
}
```

And then:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(ItemsResponse<City>.self, from: data)
    print(result)

    let cities = result.items
    print(cities)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: one more question plz, is it recommended to use pods?

Comment: Nope. Back in Swift 3 some would have recommended SwiftyJSON (though I personally never was a fan of it), but `JSONDecoder` obviates the need for that.

Comment: @AidogdyShahyrov - FYI, your revised question has changed the JSON a bit, so I've changed my code here to match. But hopefully it illustrates the basic idea, even if the details of your JSON format aren't quite right.